# in google analytics, how do I get the site from the AccountEntry?

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

in google analytics, how do I get the site from the AccountEntry ?

looks like that if I do:

- entry.getProperty("ga:accountName")
- entry.getTitle().getPlainText()

I get it. but is this correct ?
where is it documented ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [XML account feed reference](http://code.google.com/p/ga-api-http-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/v2/accountFeedResponse.xml) with all the data returned from the API.
[Here](http://code.google.com/p/ga-api-java-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/v2/AccountFeedExample.java) a Java example  that access all the important account feed information:

```
for (AccountEntry entry : accountFeed.getEntries()) {
    System.out.println(
      "\nWeb Property Id = " + entry.getProperty("ga:webPropertyId") +
      "\nAccount Name    = " + entry.getProperty("ga:accountName") +
      "\nAccount ID      = " + entry.getProperty("ga:accountId") +
      "\nProfile Name    = " + entry.getTitle().getPlainText() +
      "\nProfile ID      = " + entry.getProperty("ga:profileId") +
      "\nTable Id        = " + entry.getTableId().getValue() +
      "\nCurrency        = " + entry.getProperty("ga:currency") +
      "\nTimeZone        = " + entry.getProperty("ga:timezone") +
      (entry.hasCustomVariables() ? "\nThis profile has custom variables" : "") +
      (entry.hasGoals() ? "\nThis profile has goals" : ""));
  }
```

This is a sample result:

```
Web Property Id = UA-4276604-4
Account Name    = www.mainsite.net
Account ID      = 4246204
Profile Name    = www.systempuntoout.com
Profile ID      = 26084768
Table Id        = ga:26084768
Currency        = USD
TimeZone        = Europe/Rome
```

Use the following code to get the site as requested:

```
entry.getTitle().getPlainText()
```

Comment: Updated..use getTitle().getPlainText().